# How to add image in a skp file via Sketchup C sdk?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sketchup

I have used following Code fragment in Visual Studio with Sketchup-C API:

`SUImageRef image = SU_INVALID;
SUImageCreateFromFile(&image,"D:\Pictures\3.bmp");
SUEntitiesAddImage(entities, image);`

but the Image is not being shown in the formed .skp file

Plus can anyone please tell if there is any Tutorial for explaining Sketchup C API? The Documentation is not helpful

Comment: Did you check the results of the function calls?

Comment: yeah, I got it working, the filepath was creating the error, I saw it with help of results of function calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try escaping the backslashes in the path?
 `"D:\\Pictures\\3.bmp"`

Comment: Sorry, maybe it seemed unescaped just due to SO formatting it.